# changing value of datetimefield from instance method

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime

I have class Event and class Participant, which has foreign key to Event.
In Event I have:

```
model_changed_stamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

Many participant are taking part in one even.

When any of the instances of class Event changes, or the new one is being created I would like that the value in `model_changed_stamp` will be updated. In fact I have many other classes like Building, which also have foreign key to Event, and I would like to also keep track of changes.

I came up with idea to use instance class method in `Event`. I tried:

```
def model_changed(self):
    value = getattr(self, 'model_changed_stamp')
    value = datetime.now()
    setattr(self, 'model_changed_stamp', value)
```

and then in save() of Participant, or Building I would like to fire `self.event.model_changed()`

I would like know how to do it RIGHT. Should I use signals?

---

UPDATE 0: 
According to some reading (e.g Two scoops of Django) use of signals is an overkill for this case.

---

UPDATE 1: Following suggestions of [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) in Participant class in `save(self)` method I try:

```
def save(self):
    if self.id is None:
        self.event.model_changed()
```

In `Event` I defined `model_changed` as follows:

```
def model_changed(self):
    self.model_changed_stamp = datetime.now()
    self.save()
```

And it is not working - not updating the date, when it should i.e when the new Participant is created.

UPDATE 2: WORKING!!! ;-)

after adding: `self.save()` as last line in `model_changed` method.

Comment: the three lines in your implementaion of `model_changed` can simply be written as `self.model_changed_stamp = datetime.now()`

Comment: Have you considered just keeping the `changed_stamp` field on Event, instead of needing all these related models to stay updated as well?

Comment: @SohanJain there will be many other classes having Event as FK, and informing it about change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set it directly? Why all this mucking about with getattr and setattr?

```
def model_changed(self):
    self.model_changed_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
```

An even better solution is to define the fields with `auto_now=True`, so they will be automatically updated with the current time whenever you save.

Comment: +1 looks nice and simply! Will it test, and if works I'll accept it for sure.

Comment: I tried it. Details in update 1 of my answer, but it is not updating the date in `model_changed_stamp` field in Event.

Comment: `self.save()` was needed to be added to your method for it to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, signals is good tool for your task.

You can wite:

```
model_changed_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) for `auto_now` feature.

and then:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save)
def post_save_event_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not sender in [Building, Participant, ...]:
        return

    instance.event.save() #updates model_changed_stamp
```

Comment: and how to send the signal?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#sending-signals)